# Dispay a complex html table

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm using Angularjs and Twitter bootstrap. I want to display a list in a html table. This list contains items and corresponding subitems.
Example of what I want to display:

**Fruits (3)**
Apple
Orange
Banana

**Vegetables (2)**
Carrot
Potatoes

CSS style of Fruits (3) and Vegetables (2) is the same but different than the CSS style of the other elements.
I want to display that in a single table.

I have no idea of how to do that(except than creating a list object that contains the exact data that is displayed, ie : [Fruits (3), Apple, Orange, Banana, Vegetables (3), Carrot, Potatoes])

EDIT : 
Is it possible to apply one style to 'Fruits' and 'Vegetables' , and another style to their subitems?

Comment: can you show us the code what are you trying to do.

Comment: I haven't started yet. I was just wondering if I have to work on the creation of the list, or if there s another way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list with categories and items:

(plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/so6vrXMsSkoI1o4ncVX1/preview)

on js:

```
$scope.categories = [
    { cat: 'Fruits', items: [ 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana' ] },
    { cat: 'Vegetables', items: [ 'Carrot', 'Potatoes' ] }
];
```

and, on html, to render:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="c in categories">
    {{c.cat}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in c.items">
        {{i}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>      
</ul>
```

on plunkr, has the sample with <table> too

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. In the table solution, do you know if it would be possible to set a different style to 'Fruit' and 'Vegetable' rows? As their corresponding table is included in the same <td>, I m not sure if it's possible or not.

Comment: A simple idea would be to use c.cat as class name in category ul and then style ul.Vegetables {background: green} or something.

Comment: Like @alou write, you can use something like <ul ng-class="c.cat"> and a style like .Fruits li { color: #840; } to change colors to specific category.